# Equi-distributed sequences for a doubling map?

Tags: ergodic-theory, equidistribution

Let us consider the doubling map $\tau:X:=[0,1)\to X:=[0,1)$ defined by 
$$\tau(x):= 2x-\lfloor 2x \rfloor=2x\,\text{mod}\,1
$$
It is well-known that $\tau$ is ergodic and hence for any continuous function $f$ (integrable is enough), the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\tau^k(x))}{n}=\int_X f(x) dx
$$
is valid for a.e. $x$. My question, what are the points that make this limit valid? That is, given $x_0\in [0,1)$, let us define 
$$x_n:=\tau^n(x_0) \quad \forall\,n\geq 1.
$$ When the seqeuence $\{x_n\}$ is equi-distributed? Or, when the following identity is ture
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x_k)}{n}=\int_X f(x) dx\quad \forall \,f\in C(X).
$$
Is $x_0$ irrational enough?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is that $x_0$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) in base $2$.  Irrationality is not sufficient.

Comment: Thx. What is the resource? Could you give me some reference

Comment: Is there a general method to determine whether or not a real number is  normal in base 2?

Comment: Look at Wikipedia and some of the references there.  In general there is no known method to determine whether a number is normal in base $2$.  For example, we don't know if $\pi$ is normal.  However, see the Bailey and Crandall papers.